# Creating Tag Index Django

Tags: django, tags

Im using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) to create a tagging system for a blog. How do you separate and filter objects so that only ones with selected tags are shown? Kind of like how on StackOverflow if you click on django [image: Tags]

it will give you all the questions tagged django. I have tried the method described on [this blog post](http://infostub.com/django/better-django-tagging-with-django-taggit), but I get an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. This is the code I am using:

```
url(r'^tagged/(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$', TagView.as_view(), name='tag_url'),

class TagView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    template_name = 'links/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[self.args[0]])
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['requested_tag'] = self.args[0]
        return context

<a href='{% url tag_url tag=tag %}'>{{ tag.name }}</a>
```

Am I missing something to get this method to work?

It seems like this is a pretty common programming necessity. Maybe you know a better method... Thanks for your ideas!

---

EDIT: TagView based on @catherine's suggestions:

```
class TagView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'blog_list'
    template_name = 'tag-list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(TagView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=self.kwargs['tags'])

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    article = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

tag-list.html:

```
{% block content %}
  stuff
{% for blog in blog_list %}
  {{ blog.article }}
  {{ blog.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The blog_list does not exist in the template, and no blog objects are available. Rather, only 'stuff' is rendered to the template. Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Guide: http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I need. I am trying to figure out how to configure my url and view to create an archive index of tags. So that if a user clicks on a tag, for ex `test`, it will link to a collection of objects that all have the same tag: `example.com/tagged/test/`. In the same way that on StackOverflow if you click on the tag `django`, it links you to a collection of questions tagged django: `stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django/`. Thank you for your input, however.

Comment: Me too. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Do you want it to be exact or just contain django tag?

Comment: Not just looking for django tags, but rather looking for the link to match whatever tags are existing in the database. Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on "EDIT: TagView based on @catherine's suggestions:".

You have a typo, in `get_queryset` method:

```
return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=self.kwargs['tags'])
```

you use `tag` and not `tags` thus it should be:

```
return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=[self.kwargs['tag']])
```

Comment: I have already tried that also, but still does not work. Only `stuff` is appearing in the template, no `blog` objects are available. Thank you for your input, and if you have any additional ideas that I have missed, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: indeed it should be ``return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=[self.kwargs['tag']])``, I am updating the answer.

Comment: @NickB did you try with argument as a list. This should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TagView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    ......

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Fetch the queryset from the parent get_queryset
        queryset = super(TagView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=self.kwargs['tag'])
```

Comment: Thanks @catherine, but still getting error `tuple index out of range` when using your `def get_queryset` in the `TagView` listed above.

Comment: Traceback added above, if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your ideas and support @catherine (+1)! However, I am still not able to access the blog objects that are associated with a given tag. I have added the full code that I am using above. Any ideas appreciated!