# Django ListView: Getting Tag Name in Template

Tags: django, tags

This question is a continuation of my previous question that you can [find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103287/creating-tag-index-django). I have a `ListView` that represents a list of items that share a common tag. This is the view:

```
class TagView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'blog_list'
    template_name = 'tag-list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = super(TagView, self).get_queryset()
         return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=[self.kwargs['tag']])
```

When you click on the tag (looks like this):

```
<a href='{% url tag_url tag=tag %}'>{{ tag.name }}</a>

url(r'^tagged/(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$', TagView.as_view(), name='tag_url'),
```

It will take you to a list of items that are also tagged with the same tag (in the same way that if you click on the "django" tag on stackoverflow's tag section it will bring up all questions tagged "django").

This works great, except I want to be able to access the name of the clicked tag in the current template. In other words, I want to be able to say: `"Questions tagged {{ tag.name }}"` in the current templates `ListView`.

My url looks like: `www.example.com/tagged/django` after the user clicks the link. But how do I get `django` from the url above into this template so that I can say: These are the questions tagged django.? I have already tried `{{ blog_list.tag }}`, but it does not display anything… Sorry if this is confusing (I realize it may be basic to many), I tried my best to elaborate and will elaborate further based on any feedback. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily pass the tag to the template by implementing a custom `get_context_data` method:

```
class TagView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'tag': self.kwargs['tag']
        })
        return context
```

then you can use it in the template:

```
{{ tag }}
```